# How can I select dropdown list from database using freemarker?

Tags: spring-mvc, spring-boot, freemarker

I trying to get my list from datatbase. **I need select dropdown list**, but I cann't undestand how I can it realize. Give me some ways to solve it. I use Freemarker and Spring boot

I tryed like this:

```
     <select class="custom-select col-md-2" id="inputGroupSelect06">
<#if busflights??>
    <#list busflights as key, value>
        <option value="${key.id}">${value.depature}</option>
    </#list>
</#if>
     </select>
```

But it's not working becuse busflithghts it's list, not map

Any ideas?

But actially I need select dropdown list just like this:

```
     <select class="custom-select col-md-2" id="inputGroupSelect06">
<#if busflights??>
    <#list busflights as key>
        <option value="${key.departure}"></option>
    </#list>
</#if>
     </select>
```

But it also not working ((

**My Mapping**

```
<form action="/public/main/search" method="get">
```

**My controller**

*@RequestMapping("/main/search")* ....
                                   ...

```
List<BusFlight> busflights = busFlightService.search(departure, arrival, date);

if (busflights != null) {
    model.addAttribute("busflights", busflights);
} else {
    model.addAttribute("busflightsError", "no flights");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

From as much I can see from the question, it should be probably like this:

```
<select class="custom-select col-md-2" id="inputGroupSelect06">
  <#list busflights! as busflight>
    <option value="${busflight.id}">${busflight.departure}</option>
  </#list>
</select>
```

(Note that the `!` at the end of `busflights!` is just to handle the case when `busflights` is `null`. But your question is more about maps VS lists, so it's beside the point.)